# Search with index is slower than without index in pytables when the result is large

Tags: python, indexing, hdf5, pytables

The following code create a test hdf5 file:

```
from tables import *

class KeyValue(IsDescription):
    key = StringCol(itemsize=30, dflt=" ", pos=0)  # character String
    value = Int64Col(dflt=0, pos=1)

f = open_file("keyvalue.h5", "w")    
kv = f.create_table("/", "keyvalues", KeyValue)

import string
import random

for j in range(20):
    values = []
    for i in xrange(100000):
        key = "".join(random.sample(string.uppercase, 5))
        value = random.randint(0, 1000000)
        values.append((key, value))
    kv.append(values)

f.close()
```

Here is the speed test code:

```
f = open_file("keyvalue.h5", "a")
kv = f.root.keyvalues

kv.cols.value.remove_index()

print "without index"
%timeit a = kv.read_where('value < 10')
%timeit a = kv.read_where('value < 1000')

kv.cols.value.create_csindex()

print "with index"
%timeit a = kv.read_where('value < 10')
%timeit a = kv.read_where('value < 1000')

f.close()
```

the output is:

```
without index
10 loops, best of 3: 66.1 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 109 ms per loop
with index
10000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 121 ms per loop
```

When query 'value < 10', search with index is much faster than without index, but
when query 'value < 1000', it's slower than without index.

I want to know how can this happen, and can you post the `timeit` result on your
machine?

Comment: Note that your code samples seem to be in ipython, not pure python.

Answer (score 1):

So this is likely happening because indexing works best when there is only a small subset of the total data set that you are querying for.  In the example that you give the first query, `value < 10`, satisfies this constraint and the query is much faster.  The second query, `value < 1000`, is just over the cusp on this constraint and thus is a hair slower.  What 'small' means is likely dependent on your data set.  Therefore it is worth getting some timing information to help you make decisions.

As you can see in [this notebook that I made](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/scopatz/8137317/raw/42c05fb5b358af7383d0e5372ca34431d28f4a41/CSI+Timings.?create=1), as you increase the subset of the range of value, the query becomes slower and slower. For your specific operation (less than on one number) there are certainly optimizations to indexing that can be done that don't apply to other kinds of indexes.  The indexing that exists now is handles a much broader set of use cases and queries. It is probably worth bringing this up on the pytables-dev mailing list.

UPDATE:

Timing figure:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am on holiday, and have no PC and hand, can you add the timing graph for no index. I will ask the pytables-dev mailing list. When the result is large, it takes more time to create the result, so the query become slower and slower make sense. But it should not slower than without index.

Comment: Added the image! And it is slower because when indexed it has to reference the index array as well as the value array.  When just doing the query it only looks at the value array.  This basically means that the algorithm it is using is not optimal for your use case.  There are probably ways to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same issue and I think this is related to this issue I created:

https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/187

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pytables-users/oQIO2hJdB6U/Oo3iDNlmN1sJ